# How to deal with lint warning "Unexpected any. Specify a different type."

Tags: spfx, react, typescript

How should I go about avoiding the use of "any" in my state interfaces, such as

```
export interface ITestState{
  listItems : any // this triggers a lint warning
}
```

when it's not exactly known what fields are defined for a list?

lint gives the warning

```
error @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any: Unexpected any. Specify a different type.
```

Of course, nothing breaks when using "any", but I'm looking to understand what would be the best way to deal with this warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable (and re-enable specific) eslint warnings at the line, block, file, an project levels. Here's how to disable the warning for the case you mentioned:

```
export interface ITestState{
  listItems : any // eslint-disable-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
}
```

For more information see: [SharePoint Framework (SPFx) v1.15 and the attack of ESlint | Disabling ESLint rules](https://www.voitanos.io/blog/sharepoint-framework-v1.15-and-the-attack-of-eslint/#disabling-eslint-rules)

Comment: Thank you Rob. I know it can be disabled, but I would like to know how to define the listItems object without using 'any'. It can be defined as an object, but then you run in to errors elsewhere in your code like Property 'x' does not exist on type

Comment: I don't think there's an alternative to using `any` if you don't know what fields are going to be in the list. You could change the type of `listItems` to `any[]` so the code at least knows it's working with an array.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but nonetheless:

- maybe `listItems: unknown[]` will do the trick?
- or a bit more specific: `listItems: { [key: string]: unknown }[]`?